# ERR while installing next.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, next.js, yarnpkg

When I type

```
npx create-next-app
```

It will ask me to give a name of directory right? So, I type the name I want and then let it run. But it keep stay still at these line.

[image: Create next-app error]

And then in the previous time when I do 'create-next-app'. I do in with

```
npm create-next-app job --use-nom
```

or

```
yarn create next-app job
```

It still got error.

And when I try `npm audit fix --force`

It keep showing these error.

```
_________________________________________________________________________________________

npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.

npm WARN audit Updating next to 9.4.4,which is a SemVer major change.

npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency

npm WARN Found: react@17.0.1

npm WARN node_modules/react

npm WARN   peer react@"17.0.1" from react-dom@17.0.1

npm WARN   node_modules/react-dom

npm WARN     react-dom@"17.0.1" from the root project

npm WARN   1 more (the root project)

npm WARN

npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:

npm WARN peer react@"^16.6.0" from next@9.4.4

npm WARN node_modules/next

npm WARN   next@"9.4.4" from the root project

npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency

npm WARN Found: react-dom@17.0.1

npm WARN node_modules/react-dom

npm WARN   react-dom@"17.0.1" from the root project

npm WARN

npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:

npm WARN peer react-dom@"^16.6.0" from next@9.4.4

npm WARN node_modules/next

npm WARN   next@"9.4.4" from the root project

npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency

npm WARN Found: react@17.0.1

npm WARN node_modules/react

npm WARN   peer react@"17.0.1" from react-dom@17.0.1

npm WARN   node_modules/react-dom

npm WARN     react-dom@"17.0.1" from the root project

npm WARN   1 more (the root project)

npm WARN

npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:

npm WARN peer react@"^16.9.0" from @next/react-dev-overlay@9.4.4

npm WARN node_modules/next/node_modules/@next/react-dev-overlay

npm WARN   @next/react-dev-overlay@"9.4.4" from next@9.4.4

npm WARN   node_modules/next

npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency

npm WARN Found: react@17.0.1

npm WARN node_modules/react

npm WARN   peer react@"17.0.1" from react-dom@17.0.1

npm WARN   node_modules/react-dom

npm WARN     react-dom@"17.0.1" from the root project

npm WARN   1 more (the root project)

npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:

npm WARN peer react@"^16.9.0" from @next/react-dev-overlay@9.4.4

npm WARN node_modules/next/node_modules/@next/react-dev-overlay

npm WARN   @next/react-dev-overlay@"9.4.4" from next@9.4.4

npm WARN   node_modules/next

npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency

npm WARN Found: react-dom@17.0.1

npm WARN node_modules/react-dom

npm WARN   react-dom@"17.0.1" from the root project

npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:

npm WARN peer react-dom@"^16.9.0" from @next/react-dev-overlay@9.4.4

npm WARN node_modules/next/node_modules/@next/react-dev-overlay

npm WARN   @next/react-dev-overlay@"9.4.4" from next@9.4.4

npm WARN   node_modules/next

npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency

npm WARN Found: react-dom@17.0.1

npm WARN node_modules/react-dom

npm WARN   react-dom@"17.0.1" from the root project

npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:

npm WARN peer react-dom@"^16.9.0" from @next/react-dev-overlay@9.4.4

npm WARN node_modules/next/node_modules/@next/react-dev-overlay


npm WARN   @next/react-dev-overlay@"9.4.4" from next@9.4.4


npm WARN   node_modules/next

npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency

npm WARN Found: react@17.0.1

npm WARN node_modules/react

npm WARN   peer react@"17.0.1" from react-dom@17.0.1

npm WARN   node_modules/react-dom

npm WARN     react-dom@"17.0.1" from the root project

npm WARN   1 more (the root project)

npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:

npm WARN peer react@"15.x.x || 16.x.x" from styled-jsx@3.3.0

npm WARN node_modules/next/node_modules/styled-jsx

npm WARN   styled-jsx@"3.3.0" from next@9.4.4

npm WARN   node_modules/next

npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency

npm WARN Found: react@17.0.1

npm WARN node_modules/react

npm WARN   peer react@"17.0.1" from react-dom@17.0.1

npm WARN   node_modules/react-dom

npm WARN     react-dom@"17.0.1" from the root project

npm WARN   1 more (the root project)

npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:

npm WARN peer react@"15.x.x || 16.x.x" from styled-jsx@3.3.0

npm WARN node_modules/next/node_modules/styled-jsx

npm WARN   styled-jsx@"3.3.0" from next@9.4.4

npm WARN   node_modules/next

npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency

npm WARN Found: react@17.0.1

npm WARN node_modules/react

npm WARN   peer react@"17.0.1" from react-dom@17.0.1

npm WARN   node_modules/react-dom
npm WARN     react-dom@"17.0.1" from the root project

npm WARN   1 more (the root project)

npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:

npm WARN peer react@"^16.8.0" from use-subscription@1.4.1

npm WARN node_modules/next/node_modules/use-subscription

npm WARN   use-subscription@"1.4.1" from next@9.4.4

npm WARN   node_modules/next

npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency

npm WARN Found: react@17.0.1

npm WARN node_modules/react

npm WARN   peer react@"17.0.1" from react-dom@17.0.1

npm WARN   node_modules/react-dom

npm WARN     react-dom@"17.0.1" from the root project

npm WARN   1 more (the root project)

npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:

npm WARN peer react@"^16.8.0" from use-subscription@1.4.1

npm WARN node_modules/next/node_modules/use-subscription

npm WARN   use-subscription@"1.4.1" from next@9.4.4

npm WARN   node_modules/next

npm WARN deprecated mkdirp@0.5.3: Legacy versions of mkdirp are no longer supported. Please update to 

mkdirp 1.x. (Note that the API surface has changed to use Promises in 1.x.)

npm WARN deprecated fsevents@2.1.3: Please update to v 2.2.x

npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure
 binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.

npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.

npm ERR! code 1

npm ERR! path C:\Users\Faijiuy\Desktop\University Classes_Materials\Senior Project 1\Test Next-
js\job\node_modules\@ampproject\toolbox-optimizer

npm ERR! command failed

npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node lib/warmup.js

npm ERR! internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:613

npm ERR!     throw err;
npm ERR!     ^
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Error: Cannot find module 'cross-fetch'

npm ERR! Require stack:

npm ERR! - C:\Users\Faijiuy\Desktop\University Classes_Materials\Senior Project 1\Test Next-js\job\node_modules\@ampproject\toolbox-optimizer\lib\DomTransformer.js


npm ERR! - C:\Users\Faijiuy\Desktop\University Classes_Materials\Senior Project 1\Test Next-js\job\node_modules\@ampproject\toolbox-optimizer\index.js

npm ERR! - C:\Users\Faijiuy\Desktop\University Classes_Materials\Senior Project 1\Test Next-js\job\node_modules\@ampproject\toolbox-optimizer\lib\warmup.js

npm ERR!     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:610:15)

npm ERR!     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:526:27)

npm ERR!     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:666:19)

npm ERR!     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:16:16)

npm ERR!     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Faijiuy\Desktop\University Classes_Materials\Senior Project 1\Test Next-js\job\node_modules\@ampproject\toolbox-optimizer\lib\DomTransformer.js:20:13)

npm ERR!     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:759:30)

npm ERR!     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:770:10)

npm ERR!     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:628:32)

npm ERR!     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:555:12)

npm ERR!     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:666:19)


npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Faijiuy\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2020-12-21T17_49_46_033Z-debug.log
________________________________________________________________________________________________________

And, some other previous time. I also have try using yarn to do it.
But every time I do it the files keep missing or the command 'next' cannot be used internal/external. Even there are script tag show up in `package.json`, I cannot run yarn dev because `next` command is not recognized on internal/external

Sometime there problem like `chovidar, fesevent` cannot be use like 

- Sometime, it ask to install next-app

- Sometimes, they will ask to update fesevents, but I do not know how?

npm WARN deprecated fsevents@2.1.3: Please update to v 2.2.x

npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.

npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
```

I also try uninstall Node.js and install and old version of Node.js

Current version:  12.0.0

Old test previous version of Node.js: 15.4.0

I have tried every possible ways. How I can fix this problem? Do I need to install a new Node.js?

Answer (score 0):

Could update your nextjs version to 9.5.0 in your package.json. There is a yet unfixed dependency issue with cross-fetch on 9.4.4. Your current nextjs version shows 9.4.4.

That should fix the problem